# Flowplayer empty in Firefox

Tags: flash, security, firefox, flowplayer

I am configuring flowplayer and the player doesn't show at all in firefox. The converted html is like so:

```
<a id="player-247" style="display:block; width:640px; height:360px" href="http://example.de/path/video.flv">

    <div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="">
         <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
              data="http://example.de/path/js/lib/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" 
              name="player-247_api" id="player-247_api" style="">
              <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
              <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
              <param value="high" name="quality">
              <param value="#000000" name="bgcolor">
              <param value="config=
              {
                   "playlist":[
                   {
                       "url":"http://example.de/path/image.jpg",
                       "scaling":"orig"
                   },
                   {
                        "url":"http://example.de/path/video.flv",
                        "autoPlay":false, 
                        "autoBuffering":false
                   }], 
                  "playerId":"player-247",
                  "clip":{"url":"http://example.de/path/video.flv"}
             }" 
             name="flashvars">
        </object>
    </div>
</a>
```

When I copy the above html and try it **locally I get a security warning** in firefox, stating that I am about to run a **potentially unsafe operation**, but after closing the prompt, **the videos show up fine**.

Here is a complete sample [page](http://5back5.com/dev/test/flowplayer/example.html), where the videos run in chrome, opera, ie and so, but not in firefox.

What could be the reason for this and / or how to solve the issue?

Comment: Is flash throwing an error?

Comment: Uhhhm. I don't know. I think not. Did you take a look at the sample page (http://5back5.com/dev/test/flowplayer/example.html)?

Comment: yeah and FF isn't throwing an error,  so Flash must be throwing an error,  try opening it in a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is this third-party javascript file included at the top of your page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://tsbgruppe.bagelsystem.de/wp-content/themes/canvas/includes/js/third-party.js?ver=3.4.2'></script>
```

I copied the entire source of your page into jsbin.com, verified that the video failed to work in FireFox, and then removed that one `<script>` tag and it now works in firefox:

http://jsbin.com/esijob/1/edit